# How to switch off or hide the standard error console using WebSphere?

Tags: console, websphere

I'm using IBM RSA 8.0.3 with WebSphere 7.0.0.17 server. Every time I start the server the console switches like crazy between standard out and standard error console views. This is very annoying because (for me) there is no reasonable output in the standard error console view. It contains data like this:

```
<af type="tenured" id="26" timestamp="Jun 28 12:57:04 2011" intervalms="34.757">
  <minimum requested_bytes="102832" />
  <time exclusiveaccessms="0.024" meanexclusiveaccessms="0.014" threads="1" lastthreadtid="0x27D2CF00" />
  <refs soft="6425" weak="12383" phantom="60" dynamicSoftReferenceThreshold="7" maxSoftReferenceThreshold="32" />
  <tenured freebytes="120485136" totalbytes="536870912" percent="22" >
    <soa freebytes="120485136" totalbytes="536870912" percent="22" />
    <loa freebytes="0" totalbytes="0" percent="0" />
  </tenured>
  <gc type="global" id="30" totalid="30" intervalms="35.420">
    <compaction movecount="5551050" movebytes="336675368" reason="heap fragmented" />
    <timesms mark="362.622" sweep="17.413" compact="697.519" total="1077.646" />
    <tenured freebytes="196453560" totalbytes="536870912" percent="36" >
      <soa freebytes="191085240" totalbytes="531502592" percent="35" />
      <loa freebytes="5368320" totalbytes="5368320" percent="100" />
    </tenured>
  </gc>
  <tenured freebytes="196350728" totalbytes="536870912" percent="36" >
    <soa freebytes="190982408" totalbytes="531502592" percent="35" />
    <loa freebytes="5368320" totalbytes="5368320" percent="100" />
  </tenured>
  <refs soft="6425" weak="12383" phantom="60" dynamicSoftReferenceThreshold="11" maxSoftReferenceThreshold="32" />
  <time totalms="1077.769" />
</af>
```

Is there a way to disable or hide these outputs? I just don't want to see it.
It seems that this "feature" came with WebSphere 7.0 because I did not see something like that using 6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off verbose gc.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21114927

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is really about the console view getting focus. Have a look a the top of the console view in RSA, there are 2 buttons: "Show console when Standard out changes" and "Show console when Standard Error changes", just unselect them. Otherwise, logging can also be adjusted from WAS's admin console under "Troubleshooting->Logs and Trace".

Comment: Yeah thanks, I found this button and disabled "Show Console When Standard Error Changes". This makes it much better! But I rather would like to switch it off completely.